# python Put Variable inside single quote

Tags: python

Lets say I've got a variable s = String
and I would like to strore it another variable like 'string'
How can I store that variable in single quotes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Trying to decipher your question

```
>>> s = 'string'
>>> s2 = "'{0}'".format(s)
>>> print s2
'string'
```

Comment: Thanks that did the job well. I know its a silly question, but searching on the internet did not help at all!

Comment: @user3207652 It's more so that your description is very unclear but it's good I understood it :D